# How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 on Samsung NP900X3D-A01BG

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I tried to install Ubuntu on a brand new Samsung NP900X3D-A01BG. It has 128GB SSD with many different partitions, many of them have the name recovery in them. One partition is for drive C and it is the largest. I decided to shrink it using EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition to make room for Ubuntu. I have done this many times with other laptops. The program said that it needs to reboot to complete the operation. However, on reboot I get this message:

```
Recovery

Your PC needs to be repaired

A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.

Error code: 0xc0000225
```

[ A text saying I should use recovery tools on my installation media to fix the issue. ]

Press Enter to try again

Press F8 for Start-up Settings

Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings

Enter returns me to this screen, and so does F8. Esc enters mein BIOS but I cannot get to recovery.

Could you please help me:

1. Understand this problem
2. Get out of it
3. Install Ubuntu in dual boot mode with Windows 8 on this laptop.

I would really appreciate any help.

Cheers,
Itso Stefanov

Answer (score 0):

You may have corrupted your installation of Windows 8. The software that you used to re-size the main partition may have corrupted it because it's not 100% compatible with Windows 8.

I hope you took the precaution of making a back up of your Windows install. If so, you can use it to do a re-install and make the partitions the size that you want from the start. You can also use the back up to possibly repair any problems that may have been created with the re-size / deletion of some partitions.

Furthermore, I would suggest using Ubuntu version 12.10 or 13.04; in my experience, they play a lot nicer with UEFI machines and Windows 8. I know 13.04 isn't totally stable at this point, but I haven't had any problems with it yet.